# Command button value with special characters

Tags: html, commandbutton

I have command button. I want display the button value as below :
View the "Requested Items" Chart

So i have tried.

```
<apex:commandButton style="background:#d0a416; font-weight: bold;float: right; color: white; height: 40px;" value="View the &quot;Requested Items&quot; Chart"/>
```

[image]

Please help me out !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess this just about the look and I found some hack for it, which will get you the exact look and feel.

```
<apex:commandButton style="background:#d0a416; font-weight: bold;float: right; color: white; height: 40px;" value="View the ''Requested Items'' Chart"/>
```

[image: Output]

**Update**: Recommended way is the answer by Vijay Ganji

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a property in your controller

```
public string buttonLabel {
    get{
        return 'View the &quot;Requested Items&quot; Chart'.unescapeHtml4();
    } set {}
}
```

And then you can use that property in your `commandButton` as shown below

```
<apex:commandButton style="background:#d0a416; font-weight: bold;float: right; color: white; height: 40px;" value="{!buttonLabel}"/>
```

Using this way, you can escape and unescape the characters that you need to display in your visualforce page.